# Pegar tags customizadas com Html Agility Pack

Tags: c#, html-agility-pack

Estou utilizando o plugin `Html Agility Pack` para manipular `html`

E eu gostaria que ele capturasse os meus elementos que usam `tag` customizadas

Tentei da seguinte forma:

```
 HtmlDocument html = new HtmlDocument();
 html.Load(new StringReader(Document.Content)); //Aqui é o meu html, ele não possui <body> ele vem carregado do banco

 var teste = html.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//Tag-Teste"); //no html está <tag-teste>conteudo</tag-teste>
```

mas a variável `teste` me retorna `null`

Comment: Tem como postar um pedaço desse HTML?

Comment: @Qmechanic73, o erro estava por eu estar usando as iniciais maiúsculas no SelectNodes, no html, estão naquele formato, mas ele não capturou, mudei para minusculas apenas no SelectNodes, ele funcionou, não sei o motivo, por isso não irei formular uma resposta, caso saiba, formule

Comment: Vou arriscar uma resposta. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Solução encontrada pelo autor**: O problema estava em usar as iniciais da *tag* em maiúsculo. Ao invés de `Tag-Teste`, utilizar `tag-teste`.

O [Html Agility Pack](http://html-agility-pack.net/) lida com o *HTML* de maneira insensível **¹** em relação ao *case-sensitive*, porém, o [XHTML](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/XHTML) não.

Sabendo disto, quando você utiliza um recurso do [Xpath](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/), deve-se usar *tags* escritas em letras minusculas.

A seção *4.2* [desta página](http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/) cita isto.

> Documentos XHTML devem usar minúsculas para todos elemento HTML e
>   nomes de atributos. Esta diferença é necessária porque XML é
>   case-sensitive
>
> Por exemplo `<li>` e `<LI>` são *tags* diferentes.

¹ O autor do [Html Agility Pack](http://html-agility-pack.net/) mencionou isto [nesse comentário](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5776327/html-agility-pack-parsing-with-upper-lower-case-tags#comment6623788_5779664) no SO.

Answer (score 2):

Consegui extrair o conteúdo com o código abaixo:

```
// no html está <tag-teste>conteudo</tag-teste>
var teste = html.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//tag-teste"); 

foreach (var conteudo in teste)
{
    MessageBox.Show(conteudo.InnerText);
}
```

Comment: e como está teu html ? Pois o código é o mesmo, e o meu "teste" vem null

Comment: haha, sacanagem, ele é case-sensitive para buscar

Comment: Conseguiu ? Coloquei meu html numa string pra simular o comportamento do retorno da base de dados.